# How to stop Plane Detection in ARCORE v1.2.0

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

How can i stop detecting planes in ARCORE v1.2.0 by giving user feature to stop it by pressing any button or any sort of command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially create bool to restrict surface detection code and initially make bool to true.

```
bool isSurfaceDetected = true;

if (isSurfaceDetected) {


            Session.GetTrackables<TrackedPlane> (_newPlanes, TrackableQueryFilter.New);

            // Iterate over planes found in this frame and instantiate corresponding GameObjects to visualize them.
            foreach (var curPlane in _newPlanes) {
                // Instantiate a plane visualization prefab and set it to track the new plane. The transform is set to
                // the origin with an identity rotation since the mesh for our prefab is updated in Unity World
                // coordinates.
                var planeObject = Instantiate (plane, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity,
                                      transform);
                planeObject.GetComponent<DetectedPlaneVisualizer> ().Initialize (curPlane);

                //              Debug.Log ("test....");

                // Apply a random color and grid rotation.
                //          planeObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_GridColor", new Color(Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f), Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f), Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f)));
                //          planeObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetFloat("_UvRotation", Random.Range(0.0f, 360.0f));

                //

            }
```

Create a stop button in canvas and attach below method

```
public void StopTrack()
    {
        // Make isSurfaceDetected to false to disable plane detection code
        isSurfaceDetected = false;
        // Tag DetectedPlaneVisualizer prefab to Plane(or anything else)
        GameObject[] anyName = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Plane");
        // In DetectedPlaneVisualizer we have multiple polygons so we need to loop and diable DetectedPlaneVisualizer script attatched to that prefab.
        for (int i = 0; i < anyName.Length; i++) 
        {
            anyName[i].GetComponent<DetectedPlaneVisualizer> ().enabled = false;
        }

    }
```

Make sure that stop button method is in ARController

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by disabling the plane generator prefab or whatever the prefab you are using for detection and visualization of these planes .
On clicking a button set the active state of the GameObject to false like this

```
DetectedPlanePrefab.setActive(false);
```

where DetectedPlanePrefab is a GameObject . This is a simplest method I know .

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using the **DetectedPlaneGenerator** class to detect planes provided in the GoogleARCore package for unity.

In its Update() method : 
The following code snippet is responsible for plane detection and after this plane prefabs are instantiated.

```
Session.GetTrackables<DetectedPlane>(m_NewPlanes, TrackableQueryFilter.New);
```

It uses the **DetectedPlane** which is one among three other trackables to search for planes using **GetTrackables** method.

To enable/disable this plane detection simple put a bool check in Update() and you can handle it in any way, I've added two new methods so that you can add button calls to enable and disable it.

```
bool search = false;

public void StartSearch()
{
    search = true;
}

public void StopSearch()
{
    search = false;
}

public void Update()
{
    // Check that motion tracking is tracking.
    if (Session.Status != SessionStatus.Tracking)
    {
        return;
    }

    if(search){
        Session.GetTrackables<DetectedPlane>(m_NewPlanes, TrackableQueryFilter.New);
        for (int i = 0; i < m_NewPlanes.Count; i++)
        {
            GameObject planeObject = Instantiate(DetectedPlanePrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity, transform);
            planeObject.GetComponent<DetectedPlaneVisualizer>().Initialize(m_NewPlanes[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

You can further handle planePrefabs which are instantiated by disabling all child objects of the component to which this script is attached because those prefabs are instantiated as its child gameObjects.

Answer (score 0):

Go to GoogleARCore --> Configurations --> DefaultSessionConfig and change PlaneFindingMode to **Disabled** in Inspector window.

or

```
GameObject.Find ("ARCore Device").GetComponent<ARCoreSession> ().getConfig().setPlaneFindingMode(Config.PlaneFindingMode.DISABLED);
```